# About the sigma-algebra generated by $n$ first integers

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal A_n$ be the sigma-algebra on $\mathbb N$ generated by the collection of sets $\{\{0\}, \ldots, \{n\}\}$.

Note that $(\mathcal A_n)$ is increasing. I want to prove that $\cup_n \mathcal A_n$ is not a sigma-algebra.

Supposing otherwise for the sake of contraction, I derived that $2\mathbb N \in \cup_n \mathcal A_n$ where $2\mathbb N$ denotes the set of even integers.

Thus, there is some $k$ such that $2\mathbb N \in \mathcal A_k$.

How do I derive a contraction from this last statement ? It's intuitively obvious that the only infinite sets in $\mathcal A_k$ are of the form $\mathbb N \setminus A$ where $A$ is finite. How can I formally prove this last thing ?

I'm open to any shorter proof, as long as there's no hand-waving involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $k\in\mathbb N$ consider the family $\mathcal B_k$ of sets of the form $B$ or $B\cup\{k+1,k+2,k+3,\ldots\}$ where $B$ is any subset of $\{0,1,2,\ldots,k\}$. Show that $\mathcal B_k$ is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains $\{0\},\ldots,\{k\}$, and therefore $\mathcal A_k\subseteq \mathcal B_k$.

(In fact $\mathcal A_k=\mathcal B_k$, and this is easy to prove -- but you dont't need the $\supseteq$ direction for this purpose).

Comment: Very nice, thank you.